# How to add dynamic dropdown menu in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-5.8, laravel-backpack

I am using Laravel backpack 3.4 version. But I can't understand how to implement dynamic dependency menu using backpack. Looking reply?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's available from the outside world. Either your DNS is returning a wrong IP address or perhaps you have a firewall that is not allowing outbound connections on that port.